# How do you modify arguments sent to built in command in powershell v2?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, invoke-command

In powershell v3 you can use `$executionContext.SessionState.InvokeCommand.PostCommandLookupAction` and `CommandScriptBlock` to modify the arguments.  How can you accomplish the same thing in v2?

Powershell 3 example:

```
$executionContext.SessionState.InvokeCommand.PostCommandLookupAction = {
    param($CommandName, $CommandLookupEventArgs)
    if($CommandLookupEventArgs.CommandOrigin -eq "Runspace" -and $CommandName -eq "cd"){
        $CommandLookupEventArgs.CommandScriptBlock = {
            if($args){
            $x = ModifyPathOrDoSomethingHere($x)
            $x = Resolve-Path($args)
            Set-Location $x
            }
        }
        $CommandLookupEventArgs.StopSearch = $true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In V2 (and higher), you can intercept commands using a technique called proxy commands.  Check out this [PowerShell team blog post on the subject](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/extending-andor-modifing-commands-with-proxies/).